# Non-increasing continuous function with zero initial value

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, monotone-functions

Let $\phi : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and once differentiable in $(0,\infty)$. Assume that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\forall t \in (0,\infty), \phi'(t) \leq 0$. I want to show that $\forall t \in [0,\infty), \phi(t) = 0$.

So, I need to claim that $\forall t > 0, \phi(t) \leq \phi(0)$ but I am not sure how to rigorously show this claim. I try to use contradiction.

Assume $\exists t_{1} > 0, \phi(t_{1}) > \phi (0)$. Then, I do not know how to proceed for the details. Any hint is much appreciated!

I am sorry to ask this seemingly "trivial" question here and thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $/phi ' /leq 0$ in the question statement?

Comment: Yes, I will revise it. Thank you for your correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the mean value theorem to derive a contradiction.

Comment: This is the way to rigorously implement the intuition: "Hmm, the value of $\phi$ went up from $t=0$ to $t=t_1$, but the derivative is always negative on that interval ... how could that be?"

Comment: Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. By mean value theorem, $\frac{\phi(t_{1}) - \phi(\varepsilon)}{t_{1}-\varepsilon}  = \phi'(c_{\varepsilon}) \leq 0$ for some $c_\varepsilon \in (\varepsilon, t_{1})$
Taking limit $\varepsilon \to 0$, we get a contradiction.

Does this what you mean? But how can we guarantee that the inequality always holds as we take the limit of $\varepsilon \to 0$?

Comment: I don't see why or how you are taking the limit. Note that MVT just gives you the existence of a point with a certain derivative between the two points in question.

Comment: okay... my bad... you are right... mean value theorem does not require f to have right derivative  at $t=0$ in $(0,\infty)$

Thank you very much! Now I perfectly understand

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$(1) \quad\phi(t) \ge 0$ for all $t \ge 0.$

$(2) \quad\phi'(t) \le 0$ for all $t >0.$

$(3) \quad \phi(0)=0.$

$(2) $ shows that $ \phi$ is decreasing, hence, by $(3)$: $ \phi(t) \le \phi(0)=0$ for $t>0.$

Now $(1)$ gives the desired result.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is just a re-statement of what I have tried so far... I am still confused to show "by (3) ..."